# How to create “credential” object needed by Firebase web user.reauthenticate() method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential;
// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential).then(function() {
```

With the v3 Firebase client, how should I create this credential object for Google auth provider (Not email & Password).

How to do it with email and password was answered here: [Email&Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811684/how-to-create-credential-object-needed-by-firebase-web-user-reauthenticate-m).

I've tried `var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential();` but according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider) it's needs an "Google Id Token" which I have no idea how to get.

Comment: open https://console.firebase.google.com -> goto "add firebase webapp" copy paste snippet. there should be you token

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. The config you copy and paste is to initialise firebase. `firebase.initializeApp()`. I'm looking for what I need to pass to `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential()` so I can re-authenticate a loggedin user.

Comment: How did you sign in that user to begin with? Were you using signInWithPopup/Redirect?

Comment: signInWithPopup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create "credential" object needed by Firebase web user.reauthenticate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811684/how-to-create-credential-object-needed-by-firebase-web-user-reauthenticate-m)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthCredential) by using [firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#.credential).

Then you can reauthenticate with [firebase.User.reauthenticateWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithCredential).

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  user.email,
  'yourpassword'
);
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @Badacadabra, I added some context.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a problem then leave a comment and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can reauthenticate users that use GooglaAuth Provider without tokens and credentials using [reauthenticateWithPopup(provider)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithPopup) or [reauthenticateWithRedirect(provider)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithRedirect) method:

```
// Create provider as usual
function createGoogleProvider() {
  const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  provider.addScope('profile')
  provider.addScope('email')
  return provider
}
// Reauthenticate with popup:
user.reauthenticateWithPopup(createGoogleProvider()).then(function(result) {
  // The firebase.User instance:
  var user = result.user;
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```