# Firebase SDK authentication what's the point of reauthenticateWithCredential?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I started using Firebase authentication SDK for Web recently for managing user accounts on a ReactJS webapp.

For changing email address and password, Firebase requires a recent login. Given the name, it seems to make sense to use the `reauthenticateWithCredential` function. However, how is it different from simply using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` again?

Would love to see an example when and how this is used.

Comment: For an example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811684/how-to-create-credential-object-needed-by-firebase-web-user-reauthenticatewith

Comment: Thanks, it -is- an useful example of how to use reauthenticateWithCredential (which is poorly documented). It just doesn't say why one would use this instead of the regular signInWith... method.