# Firebase confirm with password

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

My Firebase app has a certain sensitive operation, that the already signed-in user would ideally confirm by reentering his password.

I would like to show this (already signed-in) user a modal requiring him to reenter password and have Firebase check whether the entered password is valid for the user's email, so I can let him perform the sensitive operation. Is there an API for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: @AlexMamo I mean correct. So I would like to have the user to reenter his password in order to confirm a sensitive operation.

Comment: So you want to verify the password inside Firebase Authentication?

Comment: @AlexMamo I need to verify the user's password, yes. An option that I came up with was to just use the signInWithEmailAndPassword API, even in place of already signed in user. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: As I understand, you basically need to read the password in plain text, to see if it's correct, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo not at all, my app doesn't care what the password is, it only cares whether the entered password is correct. Imagine a case where a logged in user tries to delete someone's account => I show him password confirmation modal where he enters password => I send that password over to firebase and get a boolean back => if boolean is true I let him delete the user's account. What API should I use to check whether the entered password is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have not used this method, but I'm just letting you know based what I have explored. There is a Firebase method called `reauthenticateWithCredential()` for re-authenticating a user with their password. This may help with your requirement. please check from firebase docs [Re-authenticate a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) and a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811684/how-to-create-credential-object-needed-by-firebase-web-user-reauthenticatewith) related to this. This may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that one but am not sure that one fits my use case.

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine a case where a logged-in user tries to delete someone's account.

There is no way you can delete an account in Firebase Authentication on behalf of another user. If this were possible, it would have been a very high-security risk.

Furthermore, there is no API that can help check a password against the one that exists in Firebase Authentication in the way you describe. The only option that you have is to reauthenticate the user. This means that since your user is already logged in, you only have to ask the user to provide the password. The reauthentication operation will obviously fail if the user provides an incorrect password.

Comment: Hey Damjan. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?